# Trying to get gstreamer setup so I can develop against it

Tags: gstreamer

I'm trying to get `gstreamer` setup on my machine so that I can develop applications that use the library. I know that `gstreamer` is installed on my machine, however, I don't seem to have the proper include files and library files where I would expect them to be. This leads me to believe that `gstreamer` is only installed in such a way that would allow me to run existing applications that use it.

I have downloaded `gstreame`r 1.9.2 and unpacked it onto my hard drive. I've tried to read though the install document. Attempted to run through the steps, however, I'm still not seeing how I can develop an app against this.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be some good information about getting started with GStreamer [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/faq/html/index.html).

It does appear to suggest that the distribution packages are used for Ubuntu rather than compiling from source. For Ubuntu it looks like you will require the package libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev and this can be installed using:

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
```

This should provide the header files and libraries required for you to start developing.

Hope that helps.